# Create VM with WMI in c#

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to create a VM in Hyper-V with WMI.

```
        ManagementClass virtualSystemManagementService = 
            new ManagementClass(@"root\virtualization\v2:Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService");

        ManagementBaseObject inParams = 
            virtualSystemManagementService
                .GetMethodParameters("DefineSystem");

        // Add the input parameters.
        ManagementClass virtualSystemSettingData = 
            new ManagementClass(@"root\virtualization\v2:Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData")
        {
            ["ElementName"] = "Test"
        };

        inParams["SystemSettings"] = 
            virtualSystemSettingData.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);

        // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = 
            virtualSystemManagementService
                .InvokeMethod("DefineSystem", inParams, null);
```

The call to InvokeMethod throws an System.Management.MangementException - "Invalid method Parameter(s).

I am basing this code on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2013/06/20/creating-a-virtual-machine-with-wmi-v2/

I do realize that this is really easy with powershell, but I am trying to understand how the WMI side of things works.

Comment: Did you manage to add a HDD or some Memory to the virtual Server?

Answer (score 1):

**Basic workflow For Virtual Machine Creation using WMI with C#:**

*You missed creating an instance of VirtualSystemSettingData and getting an instance of VirtualSystemManagment Service.* 
The exception **System.Management.MangementException - "Invalid method Parameter(s)** is thrown when you call invoke method on a **class not an object!**

1. Create VirtualSystemSettingData class
2. Add Properties
3. Create new VirtualSystemSettingData instance
4. Convert to text
5. Pass to params
6. Create VirtualSystemManagementService class
7. Get existing VirtualSystemManagementService instance
8. Invoke Method

Example:

```
         ManagementClass virtualSystemManagementServiceClass =
            new ManagementClass(@"root\virtualization\v2:Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService");

        ManagementBaseObject inParams =
            virtualSystemManagementServiceClass
                .GetMethodParameters("DefineSystem");

        // Add the input parameters.
        ManagementClass virtualSystemSettingDataClass =
            new ManagementClass(@"root\virtualization\v2:Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData")
            {
                ["ElementName"] = "Test"
            };

        // Create Instance of VirtualSystemSettingData
        ManagementObject virtualSystemSettingData = virtualSystemSettingDataClass.CreateInstance();

        inParams["SystemSettings"] =
            virtualSystemSettingData.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);

        // Get Instance of VirtualSystemManagmentService
        ManagementObject virtualSystemManagementService = null;
        foreach (ManagementObject instance in virtualSystemManagementServiceClass.GetInstances())
        {
            virtualSystemManagementService = instance;
            break;
        }

        // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = virtualSystemManagementService.InvokeMethod("DefineSystem", inParams, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData.

```
   ManagementObject newInstance = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData"), null).CreateInstance();
   newInstance["ElementName"] = vmName;
   inParameters["SystemSettings"] = newInstance.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
```